# kivy __init__ takes 1 arg

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a problem with kivy :( Can you help me to fix it?

```
import kivy
import socket
import threading

kivy.require('1.9.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',9999))

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

duyuru=""

def readData():
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        duyuru=data
    else:
        duyuru="Henüz duyuru yok!"

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=readData)
        t1.start()
        return Label(duyuru)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

It give me an error says:"Type error: `__init__` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given ". And the kivy window opens but stops running :(

Traceback:

```
[INFO           ] [Logger      ] Record login 
C:\Users\Beatless27\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-05-02_40.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20             2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif,     img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.3.0'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce 9500         GT/PCIe/SSE2/3DNOW!'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 3
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single     mode, not docked
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "AndroidClient.py", line 29, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "AndroidClient.py", line 27, in build
     return Label(duyuru)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: An example how to use a label is at the very beginning of the docs: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html

Comment: Added whole traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Label(text=duyuru)` - it is a keyword argument, not a positional one.